How to animate a solid block cracking
Looked around online for a bit and could not find an answer - most resources are about making a cell fracture + rigid body explosion.
But I don't want an explosion/destruction animation. I just want to animate cracks appearing on a solid block, but nothing explodes or gets pushed out (please see the hand-drawn idea below)

How do I do this?

Just to clarify what may already be clear for you : Blender doesn't have a native physics tool for that. But still, you can emulate that with other tools or add-on.

You could use the AnimAll addon. Activate it. Create the crack on the object with the knife or another tool. Open the Timeline, open the N panel > Animation > activate Key > Points > Location and insert a keyframe:

In the next frames of the Timeline move the vertices and keyframe again, choose a Constant interpolation if you want the cracks to be brutal, result:


You can use

Ivy Generator addon to create curve cracks
Shrinkwrap curve to block
and animate under Curve Properties - Geometry - Start-End Mapping the
End value ...



Or search for some lightning or tree tutorial for geo-nodes (shortest path) techniques.
